# Block certain url from being open in browser

Tags: android, browser

Can I block certain url, from being open in default browser,from my android application ?

Comment: What do you mean by block, saying a message that it's blocked or not opening it at all?

Comment: toast a message saying its blocked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I have designed my own browser, so before loading url, I have put the condition. If url contains the blocked sites, then the page is not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to block some websites on a user's device by letting them install your app, then it will only work if they are rooted.On a device that's not rooted, preventing the standard browser from accessing a certain website is not possible by installing an app.

However, you can have your own `Webview` in place inside your app.Then you can track all urls getting open in your `WebView` and do your stuff accordingly.User will stay in your app always.That solves your purpose i guess.

For tracking all urls inside your [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) you need to register one [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) and overide below function

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url)
```

Comment: my app is a launcher app.It has a browser app in it. And i want to restrict certain sites in that browser. I am not dealing with WebView.

Comment: Even though you have a browser of your own, i doubt it will work if the device is not rooted.I would suggest you either use a `WebView` with which you can easily do it or use server side solutions for this.Main reason behind it is no client-side application code is secure for this, be it a javascript brower app.

Comment: doing all the work on WebView will make the app slow. But I want to have parental control on browser. What should I do?

Comment: You can give `ContentObserver` a try.I don't know it will work for sure or not but you can refer the second answer of [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839130/monitor-web-browser-programmatically-in-android) to see if it works for you.If my answer helped you please consider accepting it or upvoting it.